# Reputation not moving up while having 27 upvotes

Tags: support, reputation

Do you have a clue why my reputation os not moving up while the last question I asked has 27 upvotes?

Thanks, Jean-Pierre.

Comment: Clicking on the edit history shows "Post Made Community Wiki by Todd Trimble" on Sept 14, shortly after it was asked.

Comment: Traditionally, i.e., since the inception of MathOverflow, questions that ask for lists of examples, 'soft questions', questions asking for advice, or that are about philosophy -- in short, questions that have no definitive answer and whose answers are subject to individual tastes -- are made 'Community Wiki'. You can find some discussion on this in this thread, http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/247/question-mysteriously-becoming-community-wiki/, and it's my observation that many in the community support this guideline (which may be different from how CW is applied on other SE websites).

Answer (score 6):

You can see an itemized view of the reputation you earned on your user page:

https://mathoverflow.net/users/41060/jean-pierre-merx?tab=reputation&sort=post

A more detailed listing, but less pleasant to look at, can be found by going at [mathoverflow.net/reputation](https://mathoverflow.net/reputation).

Keep in mind that the [reputation calculation is somewhat complex](https://mathoverflow.net/help/whats-reputation): you don't earn points for community wiki posts and that there is a daily reputation cap of 200 points, so your reputation count might be lower than what you get by tallying votes. As compensation for the daily cap, if you hit the limit, you will earn the [mortarboard badge](https://mathoverflow.net/help/badges/25/mortarboard)!