# Derivative of reputation score over time is identically zero

Tags: support, reputation, community-wiki

I've got a smattering of upvotes on my small number of answers but my reputation has never budged. Can someone explain why this is so?

Comment: Since users wondering why their reputation is not changing might find this post when searching on meta, it might be worth mentioning at least in a comment that this might also happen when user reaches the daily reputation limit. More details can be found in answer to these questions: [5 points for an upvote to an answer?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3912) and [Reputation not moving up while having 27 upvotes](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1906).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My answer got upvoted, but no reputation increase?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4614/my-answer-got-upvoted-but-no-reputation-increase)

Answer (score 6):

The questions that you have answered on MathOverflow are all "Community Wiki" posts, and votes on these don't affect reputation.

[What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Questions that ask for a list of examples, and so don't have a single "correct" answer, are often made Community Wiki.

Comment: I actually believe that the main goal/role of cw is to prevent people to get huge reputation based on big-list questions, and restrict getting reputation on somewhat mathematical contributions.

Comment: I guess that this has been discussed here many times, but it's probably worth mentioning that using CW as a way to avoid reputation gain (as mentioned in @YCor's comment) seems to be specific to MO and a few other sites. (It's not network-wide approach and possibility to make a post CW was intended for a different purpose.)