# 5 points for an upvote to an answer?

Tags: support, reputation, up-votes

just a curiosity, how is it possible to receive 5 points for an upvote to an *answer* to this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/311780/11260)

[image]

Comment: this is not a bug, but my own misunderstanding; apologies for the misleading tag "bug".

Comment: So maybe if in the hindsight it seems that (bug) is not exactly right tag for this question, perhaps you could simply change it to (support) which is probably more suitable. (I have also [asked in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243/2018/10/1) whether it might be a good idea to introduce (daily-reputation-limit) tag here on meta - I think it's quite likely that there will be other questions about this topic so the tag might be useful. So far, I have received no response there.)

Comment: done, for some reason I cannot omit "bug" entirely, have to replace it by "support" or "feature request" --- "support" is not quite right, but certainly better than bug -- thanks.

Comment: It **is** a bug --- specifically, a user interface bug: the user interface does not make it sufficiently clear what is going on and leaves people with doubts.

Comment: and I suggest re-tagging it as bug, because otherwise the SE staff will never see this thread.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is daily reputation limit of 200 reputation points - meaning that it is not possible to get more than 200 reputation points in a single day *from upvotes*. (It is still possible to get more reputation points from accepted answers and bounties.)

In this specific case, you got to 195 reputation points (some upvotes on questions worth 5 points, some upvotes on answer worth 10 points) which meant the next upvote only added the amount missing to the daily cap of 200 points.

[image: screenshot]

This is also explained [in the help center](https://mathoverflow.net/help/whats-reputation):

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from the combination of upvotes, downvotes and suggested edits. But [Bounty awards](https://mathoverflow.net/helpcenter/bounty), [accepted answers](https://mathoverflow.net/helpcenter/accepted-answer), and [association bonuses](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/) are not subject to this daily reputation limit.

Meta Stack Exchange: [What is the reasoning behind the reputation cap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22447)