# Apparent bug in reputation calculator

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation, community-wiki

Mine appears to be stuck at 2321 -- even though my answer here keeps getting upvoted:
[What definitions were crucial to further understanding?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316785/what-definitions-were-crucial-to-further-understanding/316899#316899)

Comment: It's Community Wiki. You don't gain or lose reputation points when a thread is in CW.

Comment: Pfew, thanks! I'll be happy to delete this question if it's silly and I should've known better.

Comment: Don't worry about it. If you didn't know, there's a first time for learning anything.

Comment: @ToddTrimble I wonder whether it would be better to retag the question as ([meta-tag:support]) or - since it was originally tagged as bug - simply to add ([meta-tag:status-bydesign]). But since the latter can only be added by moderators (or other diamond-bearing  users), it seemed natural to ask you for opinion on this.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Tags edited; thanks.

Comment: @AryehKontorovich: no need to delete it!  Community Wiki doesn’t mean the question was bad, just that it fits certain criteria — mostly, that it can have many good answers, and that it’s unlikely any one can be definitive — which, for various reasons, clash a bit with the usual reputation system, and so a CW flag keeps the question open but makes it reputation-neutral.

Comment: Since the question is about situations when upvotes do not add reputation, the daily reputation limit should probably be mentioned, too. For more details, see: [Reputation not moving up while having 27 upvotes](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1906) and [5 points for an upvote to an answer?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3912).

Answer (score 5):

As explained in [Todd Trimble's comment](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4002/apparent-bug-in-reputation-calculator#comment17849_4002),

> It's Community Wiki. You don't gain or lose reputation points when a thread is in CW.

Further reading: [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)