# My answer got upvoted, but no reputation increase?

Tags: support, bug, reputation, community-wiki

My reputation score seems to be stuck at 510 even if some of my answers were up-voted recently.
How do I fix this bug? How do I contact the moderators in order to solve (or at least understand) the problem?

Comment: here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363572/important-but-not-too-well-known-inequalities/363901#363901. At least 3 upvotes? Community Wiki ?

Comment: See also: [Derivative of reputation score over time is identically zero](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3806) (and [other posts linked there](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/linked/3806)). But this question definitely has a better title - thus making it easier to find for the users who might have the same question in the future.

Comment: This is not the case here, but another reason why reputation might remain the same despite getting upvotes is when the user reached the reputation cap. It is possible to get at most 200 reputation points per day from upvotes. (Bounties and points from accepted answers are not subject this limit.) Some posts on this meta about the reputation cap: [5 points for an upvote to an answer?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3912) and [Reputation not moving up while having 27 upvotes](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1906).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a [community wiki answer](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki), and you don't get any reputation for upvotes on them (nor do you lose any from downvotes). The idea behind this is that they're **easy to edit** (for everybody with at least 100 reputation) and are a *collaborative* effort, and therefore do not confer reputation. Since at the moment it's 100% your work, this might not be fair, but it's hard to make some kind of system to 'correctly' distribute reputation among the contributors.

Usually, you have to explicitly indicate you want your answer to be a community wiki; however, this is a community wiki question and all its answers are automatically community wiki as well.

The only bug I can see here (now reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349893/295232) on the main Meta) that I can't see the upvotes in your [reputation history](https://mathoverflow.net/users/69642/user69642?tab=reputation).

> How do I contact the moderators in order to solve (or at least understand) the problem?

Well, you did the right thing: asking here on [Meta](https://mathoverflow.net/help/whats-meta). This has the benefit of being a semi-interactive format, visible for more users than just the moderators, and increasing the knowledge of other users about how the site works.

Comment: yes I can see the upvotes in your history without points added to your reputation score.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to raise a bug report in the main Meta so the site developers can have a look.

Comment: Re: *I can't see the upvotes in your reputation history.* I have noticed for a long time that the upvotes on community votes are shown in the reputation tab only if *there is some other reputation change* in the same day. (For example, if the OP gets some upvote/downvote on a non-CW post, then this even would be displayed and so would be the votes on CW posts. IIRC it is the case also if the vote is removed soon after.) If needed, I can try to find some examples in my reputation history.) I thought that this was intentional, maybe it can be considered a bug.

Comment: I have experienced now a similar situation with up vote for comment which is not taken into account for my reputation. E.g. here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364036/combinatorics-of-multivariate-faà-di-bruno-formula?noredirect=1#comment918757_364036 is it normal ?

Comment: @user69642 yes, that's normal: comments [do not generate reputation](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: ok. Thanks again for your time to answer my newbie questions!